# Is there any possible way to run my swift 2 project in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, swift

I can't run my `swift 2` project in `Xcode 8`. Is there any way to run?

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: what the issue u faced, but it is possible

Comment: You need at least Swift 2.3 to run on XCode 8.x. For Swift 2.x, you need Xcode 7.x.

Comment: while adding  the project into xcode8 .It is asking to convert swift2 to swift3.but i don't want to convert my code.is there is any way to run without convert my project to swift 3.

Comment: If you don't wanna change the code, then better to go for Xcode 7.x.

Comment: @Kavithagunasekaran are you using pod files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**set Use Legacy Swift Language Version to `Yes` In Both `Project` And `Targets`**

Answer (score 0):

You can set `SWIFT_VERSION` in your project settings to 2.3, and migrate your 2.x code to 2.3, which should be a much quicker and smaller change than fully migrating to 3.x.

If you use CocoaPods (or have separate targets in your project), you'll have to set `SWIFT_VERSION` in each targets settings too.

Answer (score 0):

if you use pods include this code in your podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
      end
    end
  end
```

if you dont use pods, then set the swift_version to 2.3. you dont have to go back to xcode 7 to do this.